# Data send to ajax by php are undefined after ajax success call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have some issue with showing the response alert of the form.

```
$(function () {

    // when the form is submitted
    $('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {

        // if the validator does not prevent form submit
        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            var url = "contact.php";

            // POST values in the background the the script URL
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data)
                {
                    // we recieve the type of the message: success x danger and apply it to the 
                    var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                    var messageText = data.message;
                    // let's compose Bootstrap alert box HTML
                    var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';
                    // If we have messageAlert and messageText
                    if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                        // inject the alert to .messages div in our form
                        $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                        // empty the form
                        $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                    // }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    })
});
```

php file looks like that

```
try
{

    if(count($_POST) == 0) throw new \Exception('Form is empty');

    $emailText = "You have a new message from your contact form\n=============================\n";

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        // If the field exists in the $fields array, include it in the email 
        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
        }
    }

    // All the neccessary headers for the email.
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8";',
        'From: ' . $from,
        'Reply-To: ' . $from,
        'Return-Path: ' . $from,
    );

    // Send email
    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}
```

The thing is that if (messageAlert && messageText) is never TRUE since the variables are that time undefined. Though emails are sent successfully and console.log(data) in js file prints wanted data.

Could you please help me to solve the problem?

Comment: You need to define $okMessage and $errorMessage variables

Comment: Hello, yeah I have them earlier in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You send the email, you create the response Array but you don't pass it to the ajax call.
Where is the echo of the responseArray?
The best way I suggest you is to pass it as a json data:

```
echo json_encode($responseArray);
```

And then read in the javascript function

```
var json = $.parseJSON(data);
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your suggestion, but unfortunately, that didn't help